# Ubuntu server does not boot after fresh install but does after entering recovery and proceeding with normal boot

Tags: 64-bit

I have been trying to set up a ubuntu server all day but as the title says the only way I can get it to boot is via the recovery option.

I have spent all day googling and see countless of suggestions for installing AMD drivers (I'm using an AMD based computer which has an integrated AMD graphics on the CPU) there is NO graphics card.

I have tried both 16.04 and now 14 ubuntu server versions and I am still getting the same issue. I've tried installing all these graphics card options for AMD but still nothing.

It's ubuntu server, so it's an headless OS. Why should I need to install graphics drivers?

Is there anyway I can use the graphics option that is chosen when entering recovery mode and booting to normal? Because that's all I really need? And the graphics driver fixes don't seem to work anyway :(

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Did you try the 'nomodeset' option of Grub?

Comment: Hi willem, that option wasn't there, I did see a post talking about removing it but it was already removed for me. I got it working with 14.04 but I tried out so many things I don't think I could pin point a certain answer :/

Comment: My bad Nick. I meant to say to add that option to the Grub entry that you are booting. This link shows how to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu. I agree it is odd that one would have to set anything graphic-like for a system that is not using graphics. So my suggestion is a bit of a long shot.